# partial line replace command

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a bunch of dna sequences in my file. I'd like to replace the top line eg. `>xxx_3-13_00021^gcd` with `>gcd`
Does anyone have a search and replace command for this?

```
>xxx_3-13_00021^gcd
TGCCGTTATTACAATCCGGCAGTCCATACGGCAGCTTTTGCCTTACCCCAGTATCTGCAA
GATGCACTGGCTTCACAGCCGTCCTAA
>yyy_3-13_00019^group_3912
ATGGCCGTTTGCGCAAACAGTTACGCGCTCAGCGAGTCTGAAGCCGAAGATATGGCCGAT
TTAACGGCAGTTTTTGTTTTTCTGAAGAACGATTGTGGTTACCAGAACTTACCTAACGGG
CAAATTCGTCGCGCGCTGGTCTTTTTCGCCCAGCAAAACCAGTGGGATCTCAGTAATTAC
GACACCTTCGACATGAAAGCCCTCGGTGAAGACAGCTACCGCGATCTCAGCGGCATTGGC
ATTCCCGTCGCTAAAAAGTGCAAAGCCCTGGCTCGCGATTCCTTAAGCCTGCTTGCCTAC
GTCAAATAA
>zzzz_3-13_00020^cueO
ATGCAACGTCGTGATTTCTTGAAATATTCCGTCGCGCTGGGTGTGGCTTCAGCCTTGCCG
CTGTGGAGCCGCGCAGTATTTGCGGCGGAACGCCCAACGTTACCAATCCCTGATTTGCTC
ACGACCGATGCCCGTAATCGCATTCAGTTAACTATTGGCGCAGGTCAGTCCACCTTTGGC
GGGAAAACCGCAACTACCTGGGGCTATAACGGCAATCTGCTGGGGCCGGCGGTGAAATTA
CAGCGTGGCAAAGCGGTAACGGTTGATATCTACAACCAACTGACGGAAGAGACGACGTTG
CACTGGCACGGGCTGGAAGTACCGGGTGAAGTGGACGGCGGCCCGCAGGGAATTATTCCG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the follwoing `sed` command for this:

```
sed -e 's/^>.*\^/>/g'
```

Explanation:

- the expression searches for a string that starts with `>` and ends with `^`
- and replaces this with `>`
- so, only the last few letters of the fasta-IDs are kept.

with your example:

```
$ echo ">xxx_3-13_00021^gcd
TGCCGTTATTACAATCCGGCAGTCCATACGGCAGCTTTTGCCTTACCCCAGTATCTGCAA
GATGCACTGGCTTCACAGCCGTCCTAA
>yyy_3-13_00019^group_3912
ATGGCCGTTTGCGCAAACAGTTACGCGCTCAGCGAGTCTGAAGCCGAAGATATGGCCGAT
TTAACGGCAGTTTTTGTTTTTCTGAAGAACGATTGTGGTTACCAGAACTTACCTAACGGG
CAAATTCGTCGCGCGCTGGTCTTTTTCGCCCAGCAAAACCAGTGGGATCTCAGTAATTAC
GACACCTTCGACATGAAAGCCCTCGGTGAAGACAGCTACCGCGATCTCAGCGGCATTGGC
ATTCCCGTCGCTAAAAAGTGCAAAGCCCTGGCTCGCGATTCCTTAAGCCTGCTTGCCTAC
GTCAAATAA
>zzzz_3-13_00020^cueO
ATGCAACGTCGTGATTTCTTGAAATATTCCGTCGCGCTGGGTGTGGCTTCAGCCTTGCCG
CTGTGGAGCCGCGCAGTATTTGCGGCGGAACGCCCAACGTTACCAATCCCTGATTTGCTC
ACGACCGATGCCCGTAATCGCATTCAGTTAACTATTGGCGCAGGTCAGTCCACCTTTGGC
GGGAAAACCGCAACTACCTGGGGCTATAACGGCAATCTGCTGGGGCCGGCGGTGAAATTA
CAGCGTGGCAAAGCGGTAACGGTTGATATCTACAACCAACTGACGGAAGAGACGACGTTG
CACTGGCACGGGCTGGAAGTACCGGGTGAAGTGGACGGCGGCCCGCAGGGAATTATTCCG" | sed -e 's/^>.*\^/>/g'


>gcd
TGCCGTTATTACAATCCGGCAGTCCATACGGCAGCTTTTGCCTTACCCCAGTATCTGCAA
GATGCACTGGCTTCACAGCCGTCCTAA
>group_3912
ATGGCCGTTTGCGCAAACAGTTACGCGCTCAGCGAGTCTGAAGCCGAAGATATGGCCGAT
TTAACGGCAGTTTTTGTTTTTCTGAAGAACGATTGTGGTTACCAGAACTTACCTAACGGG
CAAATTCGTCGCGCGCTGGTCTTTTTCGCCCAGCAAAACCAGTGGGATCTCAGTAATTAC
GACACCTTCGACATGAAAGCCCTCGGTGAAGACAGCTACCGCGATCTCAGCGGCATTGGC
ATTCCCGTCGCTAAAAAGTGCAAAGCCCTGGCTCGCGATTCCTTAAGCCTGCTTGCCTAC
GTCAAATAA
>cueO
ATGCAACGTCGTGATTTCTTGAAATATTCCGTCGCGCTGGGTGTGGCTTCAGCCTTGCCG
CTGTGGAGCCGCGCAGTATTTGCGGCGGAACGCCCAACGTTACCAATCCCTGATTTGCTC
ACGACCGATGCCCGTAATCGCATTCAGTTAACTATTGGCGCAGGTCAGTCCACCTTTGGC
GGGAAAACCGCAACTACCTGGGGCTATAACGGCAATCTGCTGGGGCCGGCGGTGAAATTA
CAGCGTGGCAAAGCGGTAACGGTTGATATCTACAACCAACTGACGGAAGAGACGACGTTG
CACTGGCACGGGCTGGAAGTACCGGGTGAAGTGGACGGCGGCCCGCAGGGAATTATTCCG
```

Comment: AWESOMECAKE! Thanks a lot - you've just saved christmas!

Comment: @steffen If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey round check button on the left of it. You can learn more about how Ask Ubuntu works by taking the short [tour]. Thanks and welcome.